# Writing to databases on Python

Tags: python, database

I have been trying to write to a database and am having trouble setting data using two different classes in the one function.

Firstly, all values are being passed through a GUI and in this case, only the following entries were passed: 'Categories' = C, 'Usage' = Charter, 'DispTHR' = 5000.

Here you can see that I have two classes I am wanting to access (airport and runway) where the function set_opsdatabase_details() will go to the appropriate class and write to our database. This is all well and good when the airport and runway are separate from each other; however, when integrating them in the same function I can't seem to get the corresponding airportvalueDict = {} and runwayvalueDict = {] to display the values I want. Could someone help me understand how to write the correct entry box values into the corresponding valueDict dictionaries?

Thank you in advance! (a screenshot of the output from the print statements is attached)
[Function in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g3qp.png)
[Output of function with the print statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adZoP.png)

Example of code in text format:

```
#edit function for first part of operational window
    def edit_details1(self):
        airport = self.manager.get_chosen_airport()
        runway = airport.get_chosen_runway()

        airportlabels = ['Category', 'Usage', 'Curfew',
                        'Surveyor', 'LatestSurvey',
                        'FuelAvail', 'FuelPrice', 'TankerPort', 'RFF']

        runwaylabels = ['DispTHR', 'VASI', 'TCH']

        airportvalueDict = {}
        runwayvalueDict = {}

        print(self.entryDict['Category']["state"])
        if self.entryDict['Category']["state"] == 'disabled':
            for entry in self.entryDict.values():
                entry.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.editButton.config(text="Confirm")
        
        elif self.entryDict['Category']['state'] == 'normal':
            airport = self.manager.get_chosen_airport()
            runway = airport.get_chosen_runway()
            values = [x.get() for x in self.varDict.values()]
            
            for label, value in zip(airportlabels, values):
                airportvalueDict[label] = value
            airport.set_opsdatabase_details(airportvalueDict)
            print(f'airport: {airportvalueDict}')

            for label, value in zip(runwaylabels, values):
                runwayvalueDict[label] = value
            runway.set_opsdatabase_details(runwayvalueDict)
            print(f'runway: {runwayvalueDict}')

            for entry in self.entryDict.values():
                entry.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
            self.editButton.config(text="Edit...")
```

Comment: Please post your code as a text, not as an image. Also please narrow down your code to the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry I just signed up to stack overflow and this is my first post. I just updated the post to show a snippet of code that I am editing.